# How to add listener on change Object which already defined with @observable decorator in MobX to use in React

Tags: reactjs, observable, mobx

I have a React component that connected to MobX state with inject from "mobx-react", all works fine.
Now I need to know that my object was changed to render another interface.
I think that MobX must have the ability to do it's without compare objects, in docs I see observable and observe functions, but it not work for me.
I write a very simplified example of what I want:

```
class Example {
  @observable
  myObject = {
    prop: 'some string',
    ...there are many properties
  }
  @observable
  myObjectWasChanged = false;
}
```

The question: What i can to do to set myObjectWasChanged to true when myObject was changed?

Now React rerender component when any @observable changed, with this I have not any problems, but how to know that myObject was changed without compare, (in componentDidUpdate for example)

Answer (score 1):

You could probably use `observe` or `intercept` methods.

```
import { observable, observe } from "mobx"

const person = observable({
    firstName: "Maarten",
    lastName: "Luther",
})

observe(person, (change) => {
    console.log(change.type, change.name, "from", change.oldValue, "to", change.object[change.name])
})
```

More info here: https://mobx.js.org/refguide/observe.html